# Why does this subquery result in different rows returned than the direct query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's the relevant data

```
SELECT item_group_id
      ,item_id
      ,invoice_id
FROM item
WHERE item_group_id = 92480

# Results
92480   215342  88902
92480   215343  88902
92480   215344  88902
92480   215345  88902
92480   215346  90690
92480   215347  90690
92480   215348  NULL
92480   215349  NULL
```

Here's the direct query

```
SELECT MAX(item_group_id) [item_group_id]
      ,MAX(invoice_id) [invoice_id]
FROM item
WHERE item_group_id = 92480
GROUP BY invoice_id

# Results
92480   NULL
92480   88902
92480   90690
```

Here's the subquery

```
SELECT i.item_group_id
      ,i.invoice_id
FROM (
  SELECT MAX(item_group_id) [item_group_id]
        ,MAX(invoice_id) [invoice_id]
  FROM item
  GROUP BY invoice_id
) i
WHERE i.item_group_id = 92480

# Results
92480   90690
92480   88902
```

I'm not sure what's going on here, I would assume that all result rows from the subquery will make up the ad-hoc table queries, but those rows with null invoice_ids are not available.

EDIT:
As the selected answer below alludes to, this is a grouping problem.  The `item` table has more `item` entries in it, and with different `item_group_id`s.  Since `item_group_id` is not grouped by, in the subquery all the items with a null `invoice_id` field are grouped together.  The `MAX(item_group_id)` selection then returns the highest `item_group_id`, not any of a set of identical item_group_ids as in the direct query.

Changing `GROUP BY invoice_id` to `GROUP BY item_group_id, invoice_id` yields what I'm looking for.

Comment: I can't reproduce your results: **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/54db2/5)**. You probably have more data in the table that are not shown, correct?

Comment: Yes, there are other items in other item_groups. Grouped as they were, is results in all the null invoice_ids grouping together.  The MAX(item_group_id) isn't allowing a few identical aggregated fields to be accessed as I was expecting, but returning the max item_group_id of all items with a null invoice_id.  GROUP BY item_group_id, invoice_id should solve that.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are after. The first overly complex query could be simplified to `SELECT DISTINCT invoice_id FROM item WHERE item_group_id = 92480;` No need for `MAX`.

Comment: Because the problem was reduced to the simplest erroring form before I submitted.  What I was after was an understanding as to why the results were different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result is different because the `WHERE` filter is applied at different stages of query execution in the two queries.

In the first query `WHERE` is applied first and then the result is grouped, whereas in the second query the `GROUP`ing is done first (because it is in a subquery) and the where is applied on the result of the grouping.

Comment: I totally see it now, thanks.  I need to group on item_group_id, invoice_id.

Comment: Essentially, the second grouping query is equivalent to (and, therefore, could be rewritten as) `... FROM item GROUP BY invoice_id HAVING MAX(item_group_id) = 92480` (without a subquery), which is another illustration of the fact that the condition would work differently.